# ajax4jsf doubles <body> and <head> tags in modern browsers

Tags: jsf, myfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm trying to fix an error with a web application, which uses JSF (myfaces 1.1), facelets, tomahawk and ajax4jsf. In modern browsers, like Firefox 12+ or Chrome, there are duplicated <body> and <head> tags (can be seen with FireBug). Obviously, it is generated by javascript, because the source of the pages does not have it.

The problem does not appear in older Firefox (3.6) and Internet Explorer.

I've already discovered that ajax4jsf tags cause the problem. According to the Manifest file, it is version 1.1.1. Will upgrade to RichFaces fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who faces the same problem: upgrading to RichFaces 3.1.2.GA does not fix the problem. A version that resolves this issue is 3.3.3.Final (or something between these two versions).